# Are document.URL and location.href considered part of the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Simply put, are `document.URL` and `location.href` considered part of the DOM (Document Object Model)?

Comment: yes, they are part of DOM

Comment: nice thanks @binariedMe, but why the vote down? I believe some people also think DOM is only the HTML.

Comment: A very little of Google will give the answer to this question. So is when you can't find it otherwise. Also that's not my down vote

Comment: I did actually search Google, but none of the results I reached had my answer. When I searched `DOM`, I got `JavaScript HTML DOM` so I thought DOM is only about the HTML.

Comment: As far as any distinction really makes sense, location.href is defined in the [HTML5 spec](http://w3c.github.io/html/browsers.html#location), and document.URL is defined in the [DOM living standard spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#document).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "DOM" (Document Object Model) is the name for the [entire standardised in-browser API](https://www.w3.org/DOM/) - not just the part that's concerned with the actual HTML document (i.e. `[window.]document`) - it also includes the `window`, `navigator`, and `location` objects.

Granted, many parts of what's available to you in JavaScript are not part of the DOM, namely JavaScript's built-in library, such as `String`, `Array`, `parseInt`, and so on - and given that people generally learn both JavaScript and the DOM at the same time it's often very hard to tell them apart.

There are also pseudo-standard components that are not officially part of the DOM (until recently, or post-facto or defacto standardisation), such as `XMLHttpRequest` (originally a Windows/IE-only COM component exposed through Microsoft's proprietary `ActiveXObject` JScript API).

...but the DOM is not always available in JavaScript, you can use JavaScript as a shell-scripting language (e.g. Windows Script Host), or in server roles (Node.js) - there's no `document` and `navigator` element there, for example (though strictly speaking, there are "server-side DOMs" used for generating markup dynamically).

And conversely, you can have the DOM without JavaScript: the DOM is simply an API specification, there are implementations for Java, .NET, and others. The DOM was originally designed for both Tcl and JavaScript, for example.